# Background split do not match perfectly

Tags: html, css, sass

Is a hard question to ask. *Looking at the codepen will give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do.*

But basically, I want to split an image (in my case I'm using a `background`) in blocks to be able to animate those different blocks with different animations.

**TL;DR;** *I want the left set of blocks **to look like the right image** in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/pgarciacamou/pen/JdwVPd) I created. It would help probably to look at the possible solution at the end of this question.*

Lets say I have this image (taken from google) I chose this specific image to make it more than obvious what is happening. (Adding to this, I do not care a lot about the ratio of the image, meaning if it is getting squished in an axis or something).

[image]

I want to split it in 6 blocks:

```
<section class="blocks">
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
</section>
```

The first obvious solution I thought was to use CSS w/Sass to align the backgrounds this way:

```
$num-of-blocks: 6;
.blocks {
  // ...
  .block {
    // ...
    height: 100%/$num-of-blocks;
    background-size: 100% 100%*$num-of-blocks;
    // THIS PUTS (allegedly) THE BACKGROUNDS IN PLACE
    // I say allegedly because it is not doing it the way it is supposed to.
    @for $b from 1 through $num-of-blocks {
      &:nth-child(#{$b}){
        background-position: 0% (100%/$num-of-blocks)*($b - 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What the CSS is doing is basically, making the blocks take the available height, then the `background` for each block should take 100% of the height times the number of blocks. After that, I "scooch" each background **up** to were it should be.

But the blocks obtained look like the image below. You can see that they do not match perfectly. My question is, am I doing something wrong? If so, what and how should I fix it?

[image]

The [codepen is right here](http://codepen.io/pgarciacamou/pen/JdwVPd).

### POSSIBLE SOLUTION (But I don't understand why).

I noticed that if instead of `.block { background-size: 100% 100%*$num-of-blocks }` I do: `.block { background-size: 100% 100%*($num-of-blocks + 1) }`

[image]

it sort of looks more like the image I'm targeting, but it doesn't make sense to me. If this solved the issue, how and why is this happening? Or why not +1.1 instead of +1 etc..?

Comment: Background positioning with percentages doesn't quite work the way we all think/expect it to. Have a look at my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456487/multiple-background-image-position/31456682#31456682). While it will not give a fix to your problem, you will understand why it doesn't align properly in your pen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this is as difficult to explain as is it was to ask but I will try my best. The **root cause** of the problem is how `background-position` works **when percentage values are used**. Please have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456487/multiple-background-image-position/31456682#31456682) for detailed information on how it works. I am writing a separate answer here to explain why your proposed solution (in question) works but not the original one.

As you can see in the linked answer, when percentage values are used for `background-position`, the **browsers try to align** the **point** specified by the percentage values **in the image along with** the corresponding **point in its container**.

> **From W3C Spec:**
>
> With a value pair of '14% 84%', the point 14% across and 84% down the image is to be placed at the point 14% across and 84% down the padding box.

---

**Why does the original snippet not produce the expected output?**

The **first block is not a problem** in either snippet provided in question because it tries to align `0% 0%` on the image with `0% 0%` on the container. Problem is seen in the second and subsequent blocks.

For the purpose of illustration, let us assume that the height of the whole page is 600px. This means, the height of each individual block would be 16.66667% of 600px which is roughly equal to 100px. The height of the `background` would also be only 600px because even though we say 600% it is 600% of the container's size and 600% of 100px is 600px.

With the above assumption, lets have a look at how background positioning works for **second block**:

- **Point in Y-axis on the image** - 16.66667% of 600px which is approximately 100px down.
- **Point in Y-axis on the container** - 16.66667% of 100px which is approximately 16.66667px down. But because we already have a block of 100px above this block, it effectively becomes 116.66667px down.

Similarly, **for the third block**:

- **Point in Y-axis on the image** - 33.33333% of 600px which is approximately 200px down.
- **Point in Y-axis on the container** - 33.33333% of 100px which is approximately 33.33333px down. But because we already have two blocks of 100px above this, it effectively becomes 233.33333px down.

As you can see, there is a disconnect in terms of the no. of pixels we move down on the page and that on the image. This is why there is a misalignment.

```css
.blocks {
  float: left; /* display: inline-block causes line break in snippet due to margin*/
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.blocks .block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 16.66667%;
  position: relative;
  background-size: 100% 600%;
  background-image: url("http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/line-wallpaper-1.jpg");
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(1) {
  background-position: 0% 0%;
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(2) {
  background-position: 0% 16.66667%;
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(3) {
  background-position: 0% 33.33333%;
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(4) {
  background-position: 0% 50%;
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(5) {
  background-position: 0% 66.66667%;
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(6) {
  background-position: 0% 83.33333%;
}
img {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="blocks">
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
</section>
<img src="http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/line-wallpaper-1.jpg" alt="" />
```

---

**Why does the second snippet produce the expected output?**

Let us again assume that the height of the whole page is 600px. This means, height of each individual block would be 16.66667% of 600px which is roughly equal to 100px. Height of the `background` here would be 700px because here it is 700% of the container's size.

With the above assumption, lets have a look at how background positioning works for **second block**:

- **Point in Y-axis on the image** - 16.66667% of 700px which is approximately 116.66667px down.
- **Point in Y-axis on the container** - 16.66667% of 100px which is approximately 16.66667px down. But because we already have a block of 100px above this block, it effectively becomes 116.66667px down.

Similarly, **for the third block**:

- **Point in Y-axis on the image** - 33.33333% of 700px which is approximately 233.33333px down.
- **Point in Y-axis on the container** - 33.33333% of 100px which is approximately 33.33333px down. But because we already have two blocks of 100px above this, it effectively becomes 233.33333px down.

As you can see, here, is there is no disconnect in terms of the no. of pixels we move down on the page and that on the image. Hence there is no misalignment and they line up exactly how a 600px tall image would be.

```css
.blocks {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.blocks .block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 16.66667%;
  position: relative;
  background-size: 100% 700%;
  background-image: url("http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/line-wallpaper-1.jpg");
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(1) {
  background-position: 0% 0%;
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(2) {
  background-position: 0% 16.66667%;
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(3) {
  background-position: 0% 33.33333%;
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(4) {
  background-position: 0% 50%;
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(5) {
  background-position: 0% 66.66667%;
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(6) {
  background-position: 0% 83.33333%;
}
img {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="blocks">
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
</section>
<img src="http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/line-wallpaper-1.jpg" alt="" />
```

---

In the above method, the bottom part of the image (100px) would be cut to some extent because the image size is 700px (700%) but the overall height of the page (combined height of the containers) is only 600px.

If this is undesired, the calculation logic for the `background-size` and `background-position` can be modified like below (included only the modified portions):

```
.block { 
  background-size: 100% $h*$num-of-blocks;
  @for $b from 1 through $num-of-blocks {
    &:nth-child(#{$b}){
      background-position: 0% ($h/($num-of-blocks - 1))*($b - 1);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.blocks {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.blocks .block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 16.66667%;
  position: relative;
  background-size: 100% 600%;
  background-image: url("http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/line-wallpaper-1.jpg");
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(1) {
  background-position: 0% 0%;
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(2) {
  background-position: 0% 20%;
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(3) {
  background-position: 0% 40%;
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(4) {
  background-position: 0% 60%;
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(5) {
  background-position: 0% 80%;
}
.blocks .block:nth-child(6) {
  background-position: 0% 100%;
}
img {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="blocks">
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
  <article class="block"></article>
</section>
<img src="http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/line-wallpaper-1.jpg" alt="" />
```

Calculation logic is similar to the above except with different set of values. For **second block**:

- **Point in Y-axis on the image** - 20% of 600px which is 120px down.
- **Point in Y-axis on the container** - 20% of 100px which is 20px down. But because we already have a block of 100px above this block, it effectively becomes 120px down.

Similarly, **for the third block**:

- **Point in Y-axis on the image** - 40% of 600px which is 240px down.
- **Point in Y-axis on the container** - 40% of 100px which is 40px down. But because we already have two blocks of 100px above this, it effectively becomes 240px down.

Comment: Every time I think I know the full spec, I learn something new! Thanks @Harry!

Comment: @camou: Avoiding the cut is pretty simple. We would just need to modify the calculation logic for position and size. Please refer to the last part of my answer (update).

Comment: The only problem I see with this "work around" is that it cuts a little bit the image in the y-axis, as you can see in this codepen: http://codepen.io/pgarciacamou/pen/KpJpWd. The other solution would be to actually put an <img> inside the blocks and make the blocks "overflow: hidden" this way we can position them accordingly. Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/pgarciacamou/pen/xGMGYY .. A little more straight forward.

Comment: Oh, I just saw your update xD. Thanks! Exactly what I needed ;)