# Background-position anomolies

Tags: css, pseudo-class, background-position

This CSS positions a sprite so that the top-left of the sprite appears at the 50% centre position;

```
.al-for-you h2::after, .taster-cta h2::after {
    background: url("images/kick-30.png") no-repeat scroll 50% -32px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

changing to this;

```
background: url("images/kick-30.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 0;
```

positions the (other) sprite correctly, ie it's centred within it's container. but this;

```
background: url("images/kick-30.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 100%;
```

has the same offset as the first example.

It it simply the case I can't centre sprites with background percentages and will have to use separate images? Or am I missing something?

Firebug is no help here - I thought changing scroll to fixed would be the answer but the background simply disappears with no clue as to where it's gone.

Can be seen on the page http://development.actionlearningassociates.co.uk/action-learning-2

Comment: Background positioning with percentages doesn't work the way we expect to. See if [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456487/multiple-background-image-position/31456682#31456682) helps.

Comment: Quoting W3C Spec:
A percentage X aligns the point X% across (for horizontal) or down (for vertical) the image with the point X% across (for horizontal) or down (for vertical) the element's padding box. For example, with a value pair of '0% 0%',the upper left corner of the image is aligned with the upper left corner of the padding box. A value pair of '100% 100%' places the lower right corner of the image in the lower right corner of the padding box. With a value pair of '14% 84%', the point 14% across and 84% down the image is to be placed at the point 14% across and 84% down the padding box.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Does it not help? If it doesn't please create an simple demo (using Stack Snippets or JSFiddle) to explain your problem. In the site that you linked, I don't see the image in horizontal center for any of three settings you mentioned in question.

Comment: I will when I get a moment. Basically my code appears to be in accordance with the W3C spec but the result doesn't match it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chrispink/m47rh3oy/1/
You can see the first image is offset to the right from the second. They are two sprites 60 x 30 in a 60 x 60 file vertically aligned. The offset is 30 px, 50% appears to work properly in the first but not in the 2nd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem for the misalignment in  case of the `h2::after` element (but not the anchor) is because of from where the `h2::after` element starts. It starts at an offset of `10px` because of the `padding` set on its parent. Because of this offset the image looks as though it is not in center even though it actually is. I **have added a red border** in the below snippet for you to **visually see it**.

```css
.al-for-you {
  background: #bbccba none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.al-for-you h2 {
  background: #11696a none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 30px !important;
  padding: 9px 10px !important;
  position: relative;
}
.al-for-you h2::after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://development.actionlearningassociates.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ala/images/kick-30.png") no-repeat scroll 50% -32px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.al-for-you .cta {
  background: #106a6a url("http://development.actionlearningassociates.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ala/images/kick-30.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="al-for-you">
  <div class="thumbnail-container">
    <h2>Is action learning for you?</h2>
    <p>
      <p>If you’re ready for change, if you feel stuck right now, or are perhaps facing resistance within your organisation, Action Learning will help.</p>
      <p>You will be able to share your experiences with a small group of peers in our Action Learning Sets, and take away actions you can implement straight away.</p>
      <a class="cta" href="/contact"> Get in touch... </a>
  </div>
```

---

There are three ways to fix this issue and they are as follows:

- By removing `padding` on the parent. But I **don't think this is a good option for you** because it would affect positioning of the text etc.
- Or alternately, you can set the `width` of the `h2::after` element to `100% - 20px` (20px because of a 10px padding on either side). This can be done using `calc` feature like in the below snippet.

  ```
  .al-for-you h2::after {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://development.actionlearningassociates.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ala/images/kick-30.png") no-repeat scroll 50% -32px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 20px); /* modified width setting */
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .al-for-you {
    background: #bbccba none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .al-for-you h2 {
    background: #11696a none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 30px !important;
    padding: 9px 10px !important;
    position: relative;
  }
  .al-for-you h2::after {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://development.actionlearningassociates.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ala/images/kick-30.png") no-repeat scroll 50% -32px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
  }
  .al-for-you .cta {
    background: #106a6a url("http://development.actionlearningassociates.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ala/images/kick-30.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 0;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 40px 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="al-for-you">
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
      <h2>Is action learning for you?</h2>
      <p>
        <p>If you’re ready for change, if you feel stuck right now, or are perhaps facing resistance within your organisation, Action Learning will help.</p>
        <p>You will be able to share your experiences with a small group of peers in our Action Learning Sets, and take away actions you can implement straight away.</p>
        <a class="cta" href="/contact"> Get in touch... </a>
    </div>
  ```
- Or, since you are already using absolute positioning for the `h2::after` element you could just set the left position as 0px and leave the width as 100% like in the below snippet.

  ```
  .al-for-you h2::after {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://development.actionlearningassociates.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ala/images/kick-30.png") no-repeat scroll 50% -32px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px; /* add this */
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .al-for-you {
    background: #bbccba none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .al-for-you h2 {
    background: #11696a none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 30px !important;
    padding: 9px 10px !important;
    position: relative;
  }
  .al-for-you h2::after {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://development.actionlearningassociates.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ala/images/kick-30.png") no-repeat scroll 50% -32px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .al-for-you .cta {
    background: #106a6a url("http://development.actionlearningassociates.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ala/images/kick-30.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 0;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 40px 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="al-for-you">
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
      <h2>Is action learning for you?</h2>
      <p>
        <p>If you’re ready for change, if you feel stuck right now, or are perhaps facing resistance within your organisation, Action Learning will help.</p>
        <p>You will be able to share your experiences with a small group of peers in our Action Learning Sets, and take away actions you can implement straight away.</p>
        <a class="cta" href="/contact"> Get in touch... </a>
    </div>
  ```

Comment: Yes, so yes. Thank you for explaining it so clearly. I like your 3rd solution, as you say, it's already position:absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this way,

```
.al-for-you h2::after, .taster-cta h2::after {
    background: url("images/kick-30.png") no-repeat scroll;
    background-position-x:  /*applicable value*/;
    background-position-y:  /*applicable value*/;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hope it will work for you...

Good Luck ['}