# css image background position dynamic

Tags: html, css

I was working in a webapp (**html** / **css**) and I was asking myself if it's possible with css get what I've asked in the title.

I have this html:

```
<input type="text" class="custom-bg">
```

And this css:

```
.custom-bg { 
  background: url(icons.png) right -4579px no-repeat; 
  background-size: 39px 39px; //Size of the icon
}
```

My input is not always the same size, it may change if you resize the browser.
I want to put that icon (it's a down-arrow) in the right top corner, that's why I have `right` in the `background` property.

I want something like position: right **5%** instead of a fixed position or value (number).

Is possible? (I mean the css-way, no js) It's an big webapp and there are some classes I can't touch.

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried? You can write relative and absolute values in `background-position`. Like `5% 20px`

Comment: Yes, I did, but not worked. Thats why I wanted to confirm. As I said it's a very big site, and it has a lot of classes, maybe that's the problem. Im going to try again

Comment: Something tells me that maybe your problem is because of how percentage based background positioning works. The explanation in this answer could help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456487/multiple-background-image-position?lq=1

Comment: Thanks you both, Im trying in my localhost and it's working, but in my pre environment not works. I will find why not. Thanks you. Great post btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baumann,

Absolutely that is possible, and I use this all of the time for input fields, especially with Search inputs. What you'll need to do is:

```
.custom-bg { 
  background: url(icons.png) no-repeat 95% 0px; 
  /*background-size: 39px 39px; //Size of the icon*/
}
```

As long as your icon is sized correctly in your file, you will not need the background size, and the 95% means that the icon will be placed to the far right of the input field, and the 0px is for your top to bottom spacing. You can adjust that percentage accordingly.

Comment: I think I need the `background-size` since it's not a single icon, it's a sprite image of 50px x 10000px (width / height)

Comment: I see. That is another issue that I've run into. For input fields, I've had to create separate image files. I also like to use sprite's for CSS images, that way there is only one essential image you need to upload and then reference within your CSS. Not the case for input fields though :/